# How to get state values of other component in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, components, state

```
showConfirmationMessage = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Confirmation Message',
      'Proceed?',
      [
        {text: 'BACK', onPress: () => this.setState({ loading: false })},
        {text: 'CONFIRM', onPress: () => this._getTaskData()},
      ],

      {cancelable: false},
    );
  }



_getTaskData = () => {
    console.log(this.component2.getValue());
}
```

This is how I called the function.
When I called _getTaskData() directly, it works fine. But, when I call it like above (through the confirmation message), it gives the error.

Answer (score 1):

Write a function inside `Component2` to get your input values:

```
getValue = () => {
    return this.state.inputValue;
}
```

and set a reference for your `Component2` inside `Component1`

```
<Component2 ref={r => this.component2 = r} />
```

Now you can get your input value with your `this.component2` reference

```
this.component2.getValue();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it. But it gives the following error.                                              [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_this.component2.getValue')]

Comment: @SennenDeAlmeida where do you use `this.component2.getValue()` ??

Comment: @SennenDeAlmeida you are not using the correct `this` for referring `component2.getValue()`. Probably because you must be losing this's context.

Comment: But, I just found that this error comes only when I call this function after other function. When I press the button, it shows a confirmation message. When confirmed, it executes the this.component2.getValue() function. But, gives error. But, when I call this.component2.getValue() directly without confirmation message, it works fine. So confused why this error occurs.

Comment: @SennenDeAlmeida What do you mean by 'confirmation message'?

Comment: @SiSa I used this.component2.getValue() inside a function in component 1.

Comment: make sure that you use `this.component2.getValue()` inside arrow function

Comment: @SiSa 'Confirmation message' means, an alert that asks to confirm to proceed. If press confirm button in the alert, it continues. Otherwise, it does not continue.

Comment: @SiSa This is how I used it.                _getComponentData = () => {
    console.log(this.component2.getValue());
  }

Comment: please edit your question and include your code that I can check

Comment: @SiSa I've updated the question. Can you please check it and help me? Plzzzzz........

Comment: @SennenDeAlmeida I write exactly your code, and it's worked!

Comment: Do you write reference correctly? `<Component2 ref={r => this.component2 = r} />`

Comment: @SiSa Yes, the reference is exactly same as yours. I retried and getting the error. [null is not an object (evaluting '_this.component2.getValue'). WHen I bypassed the confirmation alert, it works fine.

Comment: do you call it after `componentDidMount`?

Comment: Sorry, that means? I'm calling the function after typing something in the text input. So, componentDidMount() does not affect it, right?